# Where can I upload Elixir docs?

Tags: elixir

Most python project host their docs on readthedocs.org. Is there some site we can host our Elixir project docs, or is there a way to put them up on readthedocs without running them through sphinx ?

Answer (score 3):

Elixir docs themselves are generated with ExDoc, which basically compiles Elixir docs to html/css/js files. We are currently hosting the [docs with Github pages](http://github.com/elixir-lang/docs).

I am pretty sure someone could adapt ExDoc to output a format like with readthedocs.org or even dash (it actually sounds like a fun project) but I am not aware of any tool that does such today.